# Proof that $F_{X_1}(x_1)=\lim_{x_2 \uparrow \infty} F(x_1,x_2)$

Tags: probability, statistics

In Hogg's Introduction to Mathematical Statistics (6th edition).
[image]

---

[image]

I can't seem to connect the two parts together. Could someone give a more detailed explanation?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply because the sets 
  $ C_n = \{ X_2 \le n \} $
converge to the set $C_\infty = \cup_n C_n = \{ X_2 < \infty \} = \Omega$ (your entire sample space). It will remain true if you intersect each part with $\{X_1 \le x_1 \}$. Thus, by (1.3.9), $\lim_n P[X_1 \le x_1, X_2 \le n] = P[X_1 \le x_1]$.